# Worst webcam and microphone

Tags: usb, microphones, webcam

I want the worst (160x120 res or lower preferably) webcam and mic combination possible. I would hope the webcam would be cheap.

On top of that, is there any way I can passively make them worse (ex. Vaseline on the lens, cover in a few layers of cling wrap, etc. for the camera; somehow create static on the mic) while not making it obvious to an observer on the other side that this is done on purpose?

I found [this combo](https://www.newegg.com/sabrent-sbt-wcck/p/N82E16830194002?cm_re=usb_camera-_-30-194-002-_-Product) but am wondering if theres any worse products, or any ways to make this one worse.

Comment: Does it need to be synchronous? There's a lot that can be done with video editing.

Comment: @Obie2.0 - Yes, unfortunately it is live

Answer (score 2):

Worst webcam? Ok, then you will need something bad and cheap as a rock. However it's hard to find anything you specified and making sure it will **work.** (cheap products like to break a lot)

I recommend getting a cam with low FPS (30 should be enough in your case) and as low megapixels as possible. Try using it in the dim room or sticking a translucent sticker on the lens. Leaving glue/cream directly on the lens should also affect it in some way.

I've found [this...](https://www.newegg.com/p/1EF-006C-00001) Looks weird but it doesn't have a microphone.

> 0.1 Megapixel |
> 12 fps |
> USB 1.1

Comment: Oh almost forgot. Try downloading very big files (like games) in the background. This will LAG your cam as hell.

Comment: I cant do the lag bit - I actually need the internet working for other stuff I'm doing in the background. What would you recommend putting over the lens? I can't seem to find any proper translucent stickers, glue/cream is opaque white so that wont work, and you seem to need A LOT of Vaseline to make it work. I'm trying to get a frosted glass-esque level of obscurity.

Comment: Actually there are [frost-glass sprays](https://sklep.spinex.pl/katalog/683/913/dekoracyjna-farba-matujaca-do-szkla-w-spray-frosted-glass-325-ml) on the market so maybe they would work. I haven't tried.

Another suggestion is to - lower the FPS in OBS. Add some filters, adjust the "grain" effect, blume... There are a lot of possibilities. 


Anyway, your last hope is your own phone.

Comment: How would the phone help? Would OBS work on a live stream (ie. video meeting)? Frost glass is a great idea.

Comment: Usually old phones had horribly bad cameras. I saw post on reddit saying OBS filters are great for reducing quality. I can't go further into topic because I never used such software.

Comment: This might be an option too: https://superuser.com/a/1376409/1009295
Limit outbound network traffic for the specific program so bad it defaults to a very bad image and audio quality.